# JSF f:validateBean validationGroups not updating

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, validationgroup

Im am using bean validation with JSF2.0. I have a validation group which I specify depending on a few conditions and link to a attribute in the managed bean. The attribute is assigned when the page first loads and works correctly (i.e. when the form is submitted the correct groups are validated). However if I change this property the validation groups are not updated and whatever the original value was set to will be used.

for example:
JSF fragment:

```
<h:selectOneMenu id="unitOfMerchandise" value="#itemManager[targetBean].unitOfMerchandise}">
    <f:selectItem itemLabel="-- select --" itemValue="" />
    <f:selectItems value="#{itemManager.unitsOfMerchandise}" />
    <f:validateBean   validationGroups="#{itemManager.validatorClass}"  />
 </h:selectOneMenu>
```

Method:

```
@ManagedBean
@ViewScoped
public class ItemManager implements Serializable {
private String validatorClass = "com.rcs.itemmngr.model.validation.RegularItem"
private OpenItemRequest openItemRequest


private void onItemTypeSelected() {

        validatorClass = itemManagerModel.getValidatorItemRequestClass(openItemRequest).getName();

}
///getters setters
}
```

Any ideas on how to get this to work? I have also looked for a way to change the validation groups programmatically in the managed bean but with no joy.

Answer (score 0):

f:validateBean gruops are evaluated once: when the component tree is built. There seem to be no simple way to update them.

- You can either update them manually per component:

  ```
  //bind you component here
  EditableValueHolder input;    

  //call this to update groups         
  public void setValidationGroups(String validationGroups) {
      for (Validator validator : input.getValidators()) {
          if (!(validator instanceof BeanValidator)) {
               continue;
          }
          BeanValidator beanValidator = (BeanValidator) validator;
          beanValidator.setValidationGroups(validationGroups);
      }
  }
  ```
- Or you can use approach described in this article: 
  [Delete the components holding unwanted state](http://www.logikdev.com/2011/06/13/delete-the-components-holding-unwanted-state/)

  The idea is to remove components with f:validateBean from tree, so
  they will be reinitialized on rendering with new groups:

  ```
  parentComponent.getChildren().clear();
  ```

  e.g. if you are executing and rendering a section, you can call
  somethig like this in actionListner:

  ```
  public void resetContactsValidationGroups() {
     FacesContext ctx = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
     Iterator<String> ids = ctx.getPartialViewContext().getExecuteIds().iterator();
     while (ids.hasNext()) {
         ctx.getViewRoot().findComponent(ids.next()).getChildren().clear();
     }
  }
  ```